# SQL getting multiple results

Tags: mysql

Alright so I've got this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT private_messages.*,
                            users.ID AS userID,
                            users.username AS username,
                            profiles.img_url AS profileImage
                            FROM private_messages
                            INNER JOIN users ON users.username = private_messages.receiver
                            INNER JOIN profiles ON profiles.userID = users.ID
                        WHERE private_messages.sender ='Admin'
                        AND  private_messages.id IN  ( select max(ID) 
                        FROM private_messages GROUP BY sender 
                )                
                ORDER BY private_messages.sent_at DESC
```

Now the query works fine BUT I want to get results for both sender and receiver, is that even possible?

For example this query filters "unique" messages that were sent by Admin but I also want to check for those he received.

So basically I want to alter this query to do things bellow

- List ALL private messages user received AND sent and make sure that they are unique

By Unique I basically mean I dont want to see some message that I've sent to someone and they just responded to me, I want to see only 1 message from each person

this is what I get from the current query
[image]

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What is the purpose of: private_messages.id IN  ( select max(ID) 
                        FROM private_messages GROUP BY sender 
                )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
private_messages.sender ='Admin'
```

with

```
(private_messages.sender ='Admin' OR private_messages.receiver ='Admin')
```

Comment: Something like that but not 100%
I want to show unique messages, so for example
http://imgur.com/a/I7Gim

As you see on that picture it shows like message I've sent and received, but its still same conversation. I want to show unique conversations

Comment: What denotes a conversation in the data?

Comment: As far as I can tell; you don't have "conversation" data stored anywhere.   When you respond to a message, store the ID of the message that you are responding to like 'response_to_msg_id'.   Then you can wire them together.

Comment: Thanks, Ill do that!

Comment: Creating an independent "conversation_id" is possible ... easier to query later, but harder at the application level to determine what is a "new" conversation.   So there's a tradeoff there.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the condition to the admin being the sender *or* the receiver:

```
SELECT DISTINCT private_messages.*,
                            users.ID AS userID,
                            users.username AS username,
                            profiles.img_url AS profileImage
                            FROM private_messages
                            INNER JOIN users ON users.username = private_messages.receiver
                            INNER JOIN profiles ON profiles.userID = users.ID
                        WHERE (private_messages.sender ='Admin' or private_messages.receiver = 'Admin')
                        AND  private_messages.id IN  ( select max(ID) 
                        FROM private_messages GROUP BY sender 
                )                
                ORDER BY private_messages.sent_at DESC
```